# ts-jest fails to compile but then runs

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

Can't seem to find the answer to this. When I clear my jest cache and I have a typescript error in one of my test files, tests fail. BUT, after the compilation failure, if I run them again, they pass.

If I manually clear my jest cache, they will fail due to the ts error.

Why doesn't it fail every time?

I am doing nothing special with ts-jest configuration:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
    },
  },
}
```